# FunctionN#== Evaluating to False

Tags: function, scala, equality

This helpful StackOverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12725313/409976) states that it's not possible to compare two functions.

For the following, I get `false, as expected:

**def**

```
scala> def add1Test: Int => Int = { println("3"); _ + 1 }
add1Test: Int => Int

scala> add1Test == add1Test
3
3
res4: Boolean = false

scala> :t add1Test(5)
Int
```

**Function1**

```
scala> def foo: Function1[Int, Int] = _ + 1
foo: Int => Int

scala> :type foo
Int => Int

scala> foo == foo
res6: Boolean = false
```

**val**

However, for a `val`, I get true.

```
scala> val valAdd1: Int => Int = { println("val"); _ + 1}
val
valAdd1: Int => Int = <function1>

scala> valAdd1 == valAdd1
res3: Boolean = true

scala> :t valAdd1
Int => Int
```

Why does comparing `def` and `Function` result in false, but true for a `val`?

Also, why is false, rather than other behavior (ex: Exception thrown), returned when comparing a `def` and `Function`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first two cases yield `false` because `add1Test == and1Test` (as well as `foo == foo`) compares two different objects which implement `Function1` interface. `add1Test == and1Test` translates to something like `new AbstractFunction1() { ... }.equals(new AbstractFunction1() { ... })` (due to the specialization of primitives the actual code is a bit more complicated but the idea is the same). Since the left side and the right side refer to different objects and the equivalence of functions is just equivalence of their instances, the result is `false`.

The third case compares the *same* object (because it was created via `val`) and therefore returns `true`.

Comment: Ah. so `def` and `Function` equality comparison occur on different objects in memory which explains `false`. And comparing `val's` results in `true` given that each object has the same memory address. Thanks