# Unit testing an function returning a function

Tags: scala

I am confused with this symbol <: and the return type T=>T. 
This seem to return a function. I got a function back when unit testing this function. How do I check the result ?

```
   def prepend[T <: Message](node: Set[String]): T => T = { out =>
    ...
   out.append("test")
   }
```

Comment: Just test whether returned function works as expected.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12725257/how-to-compare-scala-function-values-for-equality

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
T <: Message
```

Means T should be any type that extends Message.

Now function equality/isomorphism is TTBOMK not possible. This means there is not way to compare a == b where a: T=>T and b: T=>T.

You can only generate random inputs and confirm that they are giving the same result. Not a proof of equality but it might be better than nothing.

If your result is `val t: T=>T = prepend(...)` you can run `t` as `t(some T)`.